# gcloud dataproc clusters list filter by !=

Tags: command-line-interface, gcloud, dataproc

How do I filter dataproc clusters using a != (not equal to)? I've tried:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters list --region=us-east4 --project=<project-name> --filter="labels.disposition!=permanent"
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid comparison: expected '='
```

I'm looking to find clusters that are "not permanent", i.e., either label.disposition does not exist or is something other than permanent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using `gcloud dataproc clusters list` as of now, you will get an internal error. If you want, you can [submit a public issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) to support the filter on dataproc.

What you can do is to run the filter by using `gcloud compute instances list`:

```
gcloud compute instances list --project=<project-name> --filter="NOT labels.disposition:permanent"
```

Take note that other instances without the label disposition will appear as well but you can exclude them by adding another label on your clusters and including that label on your filter like this:

```
gcloud compute instances list --project=<project-name> --filter="NOT labels.disposition:permanent AND labels.product:dataproc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is easier for me to go with filtering on naming convention instead.